# UIView does not have a member named, "inertia"

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I am attempting to create a button programmatically that will fade out when tapped, change the text, then fade back in.  However, when i try to write the code for the fade animation, I get the error, "'UIView' does not have a member named 'inertia' Inertia is the name of the button, of course.

Here is my code for creating the button, it is within a function that is called within the viewDidLoad() function:

```
var inertia = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as UIButton
    inertia.frame = CGRectMake(firstView.frame.width/2-(inertia.frame.width/2), firstView.frame.height/10, firstView.frame.width, firstView.frame.height/10)
    inertia.frame = CGRectMake(firstView.frame.width/2-(inertia.frame.width/2), firstView.frame.height/10, firstView.frame.width, firstView.frame.height/10)
    inertia.setTitle("Newton's First Law of Motion", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    inertia.addTarget(self, action: "tapped:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    self.firstView.addSubview(inertia)
```

This is my line of code for when the button is tapped so far, where the error occurs:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.4, animations: {self.firstView.inertia.alpha = 0})
```

I believe I am missing something in the button creation, because when I create an outlet for a button from the storyboard the fade animation will not produce an error.

Please help me fix this issue as I will be using this often.  Also if you could find a way for me to create the button's frame properly without having to declare it twice that would be helpful as well.

What I have tried (to no avail):

I have put `: UIButton!` after `var inertia`

I have tried `UIView.animateWithduration(0.4, animations: {self.inertia.alpha = 0})

Comment: I forgot to add, I have tried using var and let for declaring the button, and both produce the same result.  I do plan on using let in the final product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand from your description you code looks something like this:

```
class ViewController:UIViewController {
var firstView:UIView!



func tapped(button: UIButton) {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.4) { self.firstView.inertia.alpha = 0 }
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var inertia = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as UIButton
    inertia.frame = CGRectMake(firstView.frame.width/2-(inertia.frame.width/2), firstView.frame.height/10, firstView.frame.width, firstView.frame.height/10)
    inertia.frame = CGRectMake(firstView.frame.width/2-(inertia.frame.width/2), firstView.frame.height/10, firstView.frame.width, firstView.frame.height/10)
    inertia.setTitle("Newton's First Law of Motion", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    inertia.addTarget(self, action: "tapped:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    self.firstView.addSubview(inertia)
}
```

}

Now, you get that error because `inerta` is not declared as a property in your class, you only create it in a function. If you want to use that button when pressed in `tapped()` then simply change:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.4) { self.firstView.inertia.alpha = 0 }
// To
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.4) { button.alpha = 0 } // When TouchUpInside the button will pass itself
```

Or you can make it a propery by adding:

```
var inertia:UIButton! // Under class ...
```

And remove `var` in `viewDidLoad` when setting it.

Comment: Ok, it worked adding the `var inertia:UIButton!` earlier in the program, and I understand now that the var wasn't added to the class, only to the function.

Answer (score 1):

Just to break down the problem line, specifically `self.firstView.inertia.alpha`.  Self is obviously whatever class instance you are in.  I assume from the error you are reporting and your code that firstView is a UIView.  Now you have added inertia as a subview of firstView, but that does not create a property named inertia on the view.  In other words, there is no firstView.inertia.  What firstView has is a subviews property which is an array of anyobject.

In other words the button that you created and called inertia is now somewhere in the array firstView.subviews, though it's hard to say where depending on how many other views it has as subviews.

You could iterate through the subviews array to find the button which you'd previously called inertia, but it might be simpler to just keep a reference to inertia.  You could make it a property in your class (if there is only one such button) and the call your code with

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.4, animations: {self.inertia.alpha = 0})
```

Comment: That is good to know, thank you, however I have tried using that self.inertia.alpha = 0 because that is what I have used in the past for other fade animations, but I get a similar error saying, "'FirstViewController' does not have a member named 'inertia'"